# selenium + chromedriver hangs at start, because chrome is connectting google server first

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I use selenium to drive chrome to get some url, but it hangs for about 15 more seconds.

I found that chrome will try to connect www.googleapis.com, clients2.google.com or www.google.com:443. in my environment, google server is not accessible, so it hangs until the connects to google server all failed. this is disgusting. how can i fix it?

[image]

UPDATE：
I finally found a perfect solution, you can write a chrome extension and override newtab with:

`"chrome_url_overrides":
    {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
    }`

then set chrome start up page to newtab.
Becasue chrome will automatically disable extentions that is not uploaded to chrome extension store. You'd better use chromium instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put www.googleapis.com in /etc/hoses (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on windows) and point to 127.0.0.1 so that it fails immediately?

I think this will fix the problem.

Comment: I need to deploy it in production environment and it's difficult to do that. chrome extention solution is appreciated, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: why are you using selenium in a production environment? It is used for testing

Comment: i use it to do crawler jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I try everything to disable chrome from connecting its servers but failed.
But I found a small trick to solve this problem:go to setting page and you can set a url when chrome starts. I set it to `http://127.0.0.1:62333`. Just a invalid url that failed immediately. this cannot disable chrome from connection its servers but the selenium does not hang anymore.